# Reduce closure compiler jvm startup tiime

Tags: shell, jvm, google-closure-compiler

### Context: continuous integration with git

I have this simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

files=`find $1 -type f -name "*.js"`

for i in $files;
do
  echo "closure compile: $i"
  java -client -jar /var/closure-compiler/compiler.jar --js $i --js_output_file $i --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
done
```

which gets called in a `post-receive` hook, after a `git checkout -f`

essentially, I want to compress (**but not combine**) all javascript files in the working directory (which actually is the website root).

### Problem

each `java` obviously starts an own JVM, which takes about 3 seconds, while the compiler itself (when started) takes only a fraction of a second. If I have 10 js files, this is 30 seconds of waiting time. While [this could be actually positive for me](http://xkcd.com/303/), I'd like to minimize that time.

I've looked into the `--module` parameter, which would let me define "multiple output files", but it puts them all in the same directory.

I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: first off it seems strange to me that you are minifying all of them separately, don't you have functions being called between these files? Given how you are planning on running it (aka from bash per file) there is little you can do, a work around is to write a simple java app which does what your bash script which would solve the issue.

Comment: @lennel I don't want to combine them because the software needs them to be separated (with the exact filenames they also have on the testing environment).

Comment: this sounds like a job for continues integration, then speed won't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People have had good success with Nailgun:
http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/

Which keeps the JVM loaded.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on how that would work?

Should I start / stop the nailgun server before and after the script? Should I keep it running all the time? Aren't there problems with the closure-compiler keeping an internal state (actually relying on the class to be "restarted")? In short, how would a script using nailgun look like?

Comment: No, the compilation jobs are stateless.  The closure-compiler.appspot.com runs same code as the command-line compiler, and while a bit of a memory hog for large projects and run multiple compilation jobs at the same time in the same process.  I believe that Nailgun just keeps the JVM and classes loaded.

I suspect that starting a nailgun'd compiler instance as part of your script would be sufficient but it is up to you if you want to run it all the time.